# `gcloud compute copy-files`: permission denied when copying files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I'm having a hard time copying files over to my Google Compute Engine. I am using an Ubuntu server on Google Compute Engine.

I'm doing this from my OS X terminal and I am already authorized using `gcloud`.

```
local:$ gcloud compute copy-files /Users/Bryan/Documents/Websites/gce/index.php example-instance:/var/www/html --zone us-central1-a
Warning: Permanently added '<IP>' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
scp: /var/www/html/index.php: Permission denied
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.copy-files) [/usr/bin/scp] exited with return code [1].
```

Comment: Are you able to ssh to your instance from your local OS X machine using gcloud compute ssh <instance-name> command?

Comment: @Faizan yes, I used `gcloud compute --project "<PROJECT>" ssh --zone "us-central1-a" "<compute-name>"`

Comment: Does adding `sudo` to the beginning of your command make it work?

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the permissions on the destination directory, I think workaround would be to copy the files somewhere else maybe in /tmp and than copy them over to /var/www/html when you ssh to the instance.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

insert `root@` before the instance name:

```
local:$ gcloud compute copy-files /Users/Bryan/Documents/Websites/gce/index.php root@example-instance:/var/www/html --zone us-central1-a
```

Comment: I can ssh into a VM instance, and I am using the prefix `root@` but I am still getting the same error message on `gcloud compute copy-files`. Do you have further suggestions what my help in this context?

Comment: Ah, some more evidence. I cannot `ssh` into the VM instance as root. Perhaps it's better to `scp` those files into an intermediate place like `/tmp` than trying to enable this.

Comment: This answer is contingent on how your SSH access is setup. There are many reasons not to allow root to SSH directly and, thus, this solution will not work for the case where root has been denied. The only way around that I can see is to split this into 2 steps: 1) copy files to /tmp, and 2) ssh in and use the system `sudo cp` command to copy to permanent location.

Comment: @Drux, @Dave — since this question is referring to Google Compute Engine, you cannot SSH to a VM as `root` directly, that's by design to keep your VM more secure. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27889822/3618671) for what to do in this case.

Comment: I will note that prefixing with `<instance-user>@` to `<instance-name>` is because without the prefix `gcloud compute copy-files` defaults to `<local-workstation-user>@<instance-name>` , the username of the local user invoking `gcloud` on the local workstation.

Comment: This should be in Google's documentation. Totally unclear there.

Comment: After trying a lot of things, copying to /tmp and then `mv`-ing from there is the only thing that worked for me. Thanks @Drux and @Dave !

Comment: thx that "root" helped - Q but how can I actually copy to "user shared 777 mode directory" ? 

Answer (score 22):

The reason this doesn't work is that your username does not have permissions on the GCE VM instance and so cannot write to `/var/www/html/`.

**Note** that since this question is about Google Compute Engine VMs, you cannot SSH directly to a VM as `root`, nor can you copy files directly as `root`, for the same reason: [`gcloud compute scp`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp) uses `scp` which relies on `ssh` for authentication.

Possible solutions:

1. (also suggested by [Faizan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3688301/faizan) in the comments) this solution will require two steps every time

   1. use [`gcloud compute scp --recurse`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp) to transfer files/directories where your user can write to, e.g., `/tmp` or `/home/$USER`
   2. login to the GCE VM via [`gcloud compute ssh`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) or via the *SSH* button on the console and copy using `sudo` to get proper permissions:

      ```
      # note: sample command; adjust paths appropriately
      sudo cp -r $HOME/html/* /var/www/html
      ```
2. this solution is one step with some prior prep work:

   1. one-time setup: give your username write access to `/var/www/html` directly; this can be done in several ways; here's one approach:

      ```
      # make the HTML directory owned by current user, recursively`
      sudo chown -R $USER /var/www/html
      ```
   2. now you can run the copy in one step:

      ```
      gcloud compute scp --recurse \
          --zone us-central1-a \
          /Users/Bryan/Documents/Websites/gce/index.php \
          example-instance:/var/www/html
      ```

Comment: sudo chown -R [myusername] /var/www/html 

worked for me using a third party SFTP tool.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and didn't get it to work using the methods suggested in the other answers. What finally worked was to explicitly send in my "user" when copying the file as indicated in the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp). The important part being the "USER@" in

```
gcloud compute scp [[USER@]INSTANCE:]SRC [[[USER@]INSTANCE:]SRC …] [[USER@]INSTANCE:]DEST
```

In my case I could initially transfer files by typing:

```
gcloud compute scp instance_name:~/file_to_copy /local_dir
```

but after I got the permission denied I got it working by instead typing:

```
gcloud compute scp my_user_name@instance_name:~/file_to_copy /local_dir
```

where the username in my case was the one I was logged in to Google Cloud with.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me (precede instance with user@). Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I use a bash script to copy from my local machine to writable directory on the remote GCE machine; then using ssh move the files.

```
SRC="/cygdrive/d/mysourcedir"
TEMP="~/incoming"
DEST="/var/my-disk1/my/target/dir"
```

You also need to set GCE_USER and GCE_INSTANCE

```
echo "=== Pushing data from $SRC to $DEST in two simple steps"
echo "=== 1) Copy to a writable temp directoy in user home"
gcloud compute copy-files "$SRC"/*.* "${GCE_USER}@${GCE_INSTANCE}:$TEMP"
echo "=== 2) Move with 'sudo' to destination"
gcloud compute ssh ${GCE_USER}@${GCE_INSTANCE} --command "sudo mv $TEMP/*.* $DEST"
```

In my case I don't want to chown the target dir as this causes other problems with other scripts ...

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE

`gcloud compute copy-files` is **deprecated**.

Use instead:

```
$ gcloud compute scp example-instance:~/REMOTE-DIR ~/LOCAL-DIR \ --zone us-central1-a
```

More info:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp

Answer (score 2):

**The updated solution for this exact issue (2020)**

For the sake of exposition, we have to break the issue in two parts. The *"copy-files"* command is officially depreciated and we are to use *"scp"*, however both old and new options are limited to certain folders only.

Since we do have access to the ***/tmp*** folder, this means we can easily move our distribution files with the preferred *"scp"* command, as a staging step.

More importantly we also have access to execute scripts, or commands remotely via SSH on the instance which means the limited access is no longer an issue.

**Example Time**

The first part is to copy the **dist** folder, and all it's content recursively to the **tmp** folder to which **gloud** does give access:

```
gcloud compute scp --recurse dist user_name@instance:/tmp
```

The second part leverages the fact that we can run commands remotely via ssh:

```
gcloud compute ssh user_name@instance --command "sudo bash golive"
```

(or any other command you may need to execute)

More importantly this also means that we can just copy our distribution files to the final destination using sudo and the *"cp"* copy function:

```
gcloud compute ssh user_name@instance --command "sudo cp -rlf /tmp/dist/* /var/www/html/"
```

This completely eliminates the need to set the permissions first through the ssh terminal.

Answer (score -3):

This is to copy files from remote machine to your machine. And make sure you have ssh setup because this will use default ssh keys.
This worked for me:

```
gcloud compute scp 'username'@'instance_name':~/source_dir  /destination_dir --recurse
```

This is the generic syntax, so if you want to copy files from your machine to remote machine, you can use this.
--recurse : required to copy directories with other files inside

Syntax: `gcloud compute scp 'SOURCE' 'DESTINATION'`

NOTE: run it without root

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before posting an answer to an older question or a question that has an accepted answer, please review answers that have already been provided and ask yourself how you will add to that existing information. In this case, the information that you've given is nothing more than command-line usage output. What's more, it's already been provided by @Nekroz, who elaborated upon why the posted content was substantive.