# Don't have write access on SFTP on Google Compute engine

Tags: drupal, sftp, google-compute-engine

I checked the other posts and was able to make a .ppk key file for FileZilla to talk to my Drupal instance on Google Compute engine. I can see the Drupal file structure in FileZilla and can read files but it says the rights are 755 for access. I cannot copy my local files into that server. So evidently, I must not have logged in as the owner. But the username I use is the only thing that works. "Root" doesn't work, neither does "accountname_google_com". How can I get the right to write?

Comment: Looks like you're having the same issue as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27807018/3618671) — please see the [answer I provided](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27889822/3618671), where you're using FileZilla instead of `gcloud compute copy-files`. Let me know if that solves your issue.