# How do i change files using ftp in google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I installed Magento on google cloud using bitnami's Magneto Auto Installer and it worked well. now i'm trying to update the magento files using ftp. I have connected ftp with google cloud storage and its working fine.

but only problem is it does not allow me to change files in any way, i can't update, delete or rename the files. It's showing me error like you dont have permission to change file. I also tried to change file permission but it's also not letting me change file permission.

I'm a newbie in google cloud and any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [\`gcloud compute copy-files\`: permission denied when copying files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807018/gcloud-compute-copy-files-permission-denied-when-copying-files)

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here,

You need to download the SSH key for your server in PPK or PEM format. This links explains how to upload files using SFTP:
https://wiki.bitnami.com/Google_Cloud_Platform/Servers#How_to_upload_files_to_the_server_with_SFTP.3f

I hope it helps