# How to copy files from the google cloud shell environment to a virtual machine as a super user?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, lamp, bitnami, google-cloud-shell

Cannot copy files from Cloud Shell to virtual machine as super user.

The following code works for me, but I cannot use it to copy files to the protected directories within the LAMP stack (i.e. /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs).

```
gcloud compute scp --project "[MY PROJECT ID]" ~/file.php lampstack-vm:~/file.php
```

If I try to use: `gcloud compute scp --project "[MY PROJECT ID]" ~/file.php lampstack-vm:~/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/file.php` I get the following error:

> Permission denied (publickey). lost connection ERROR:
>   (gcloud.compute.scp) [/usr/bin/scp] exited with return code [1].

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. You also need to specify the user you are going to use when connecting to your remote instance. Can you try using `bitnami@lampstack-vm:~/file.php` when executing the command? There is a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807018/gcloud-compute-copy-files-permission-denied-when-copying-files)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I found a solution. I had to give my username permission within the VM instance first with chown. And then, as you pointed out use my username@ for the copy into the instance.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to copy files from Google Cloud Shell to VM

**Step 1:** Give your Google username permission in your VM machine directory with chown:

`sudo chown -R [Your Google Cloud Username] [Directory for Permission]`

Example: `sudo chown -R myusername /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs`

**Step 2:** Fun a gcloud compute scp command with the parameters below:

'''gcloud compute scp --project "PROJECT NAME" [Original Location in Cloud Shell] [Your Google Cloud Username]@[Name of VM Instance to receive file]:[Directory and file name]'''

Example: `gcloud compute scp --project "myprojectname" ~/colors.php myusername@myvm-instance: /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/colors.php`

Comment: Hi Alfredo, giving write permissions to your username in the instance is one of the solutions but I don't suggest you to do that. It can break the application (this is not your case), that's why I suggested to use `bitnami@your-vm` because the `bitnami` user has write permissions in the installation.

Comment: Ok got it Jota. I appreciate the follow up. Will change and use bitnami.